# Turn on Internal Exceptions for ReSharper Plugin Development

Tags: .net, visual-studio, plugins, resharper

I am using ReSharper version 8 and I believe that ReSharper suppresses all of its internal exceptions by default. How do I turn on exceptions in ReSharper so I can see exceptions thrown during a ReSharper plugin debugging session?

I know that devenv /ReSharper.Internal activates a large number of options for me, but I do not see a way to enable ReSharper's internal exceptions. Another devenv ReSharper flag for this would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ReSharper hides exceptions in production builds. The `ReSharper.Internal` flag will enable exception reporting, so if you have a plugin that's throwing exceptions, they will get reported when this flag is passed.

This will do you well for most plugin development, however, it's a good idea to go a step further and install a "checked" build. The production builds disables most internal asserts and tracing. The checked build will enable these asserts, and also, when throwing an assert, will often add more contextual information into the [`Exception.Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) dictionary, such as what assembly was being looked at, or what flag was being passed or whatever. The checked build also reports exceptions by default. Other than that, there should be no difference to the production build - e.g. you shouldn't notice any slowdowns.

You can download a checked build from [the archive page](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-).